# Console Error in React: <reactFragment /> is using incorrect casing

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error

Wrapping multiple dom elements in a react fragment to enable a single render statement to return them all. Returns the error:

```
Warning: <reactFragment /> is using incorrect casing. 
Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
```

and the error

```
Warning: The tag <reactFragment> is unrecognized in this browser. 
If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<reactFragment>` with `<React.Fragment>`

It is also possible to use the abbreviated tags
`<Fragment>`
or simply
`<>...</>`

(don't forget to import `Fragment`)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
```

And replace your `<reactFragment />` with `<Fragment />`. That should clean up your code and help do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>`, import Fragment from react and use `<Fragment>...</Fragment>` or like me, you can simply use `<>...</>`.